# Можно ли скачать (и где, если да) исходные коды электронной системы голосования РФ?

Tags: защита, уязвимости

Или какие иные конституционно-правовые гарантии обеспечения достоверности волеизъявления граждан с помощью программного обеспечения существуют? Каким образом граждане могут, например, убедиться, что ПО не учитывает голоса, проголосовашвих в офлайне (недавно найденная уязвимость, за которую нашедший ее и поплатился)? Можно ли снять хешкод с действующего ПО и сравнить с опубликованными исходниками. Куда могут обращаться программисты-добровольцы по вопросу найденных уязвимостей?

Если исходники не опубликованны, какие меры по защите вы бы могли предложить (кроме слепой веры в компетентность и добрую волю избирательной комиссии) и каков порядок внесения таких предложений в действующей модели государства?

Вопрос касается **исключительно технической стороны** вопроса, и защиты интересов граждан независимо от того, к какому лагерю они принадлежат, поэтому **прошу не** поднимать политических дискуссий - для этого существуют множество других интересных форумов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно. Исходные коды находятся в GitHub: https://github.com/moscow-technologies/blockchain-voting/tree/voting2020/elec2020.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку! А на текущее мероприятие есть?

Comment: @asianirish не совсем вас понял

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC_%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @asianirish если вы имели в виду непосредственно ссылку для участия, то вот: 2020og.ru.

Comment: просто там написанно, что это для голосования в московскую Городскую Думу, а не по вопросу изменений в Конституцию РФ
>    В данном репозитории для ознакомления представлен код системы электронного голосования, который будет использоваться на выборах в Московскую городскую Думу.

Comment: @asianirish как я понял, они просто изменили старую систему (как раз ту, в которой ранее нашли уязвимость).

Comment: Можно ли снять хешкод с действующего ПО и сравнить с опубликованными исходниками?

Comment: @asianirish вот с этим вопросом точно не ко мне -  и вряд ли разрешат)

Comment: IMHO я бы сделал чтобы каждый избиратель мог скачать свой клиент база была респределенной, для гарантии добросовестности